# Any validity to palmistry?

Tags: physiology

Unlike fortune-telling techniques, palmistry (or palm reading) has a potential connection with reality.  Are there any studies that relate any personality traits to shapes of the hand, or lines?

Comment: Whilst I am a skeptic about all established points of view. I am inclined to think that there is some relevance in palmistry. which includes observing the palm as a whole i.e. including dimensions of the hand as related to lengths of fingers etc. There are many relevant studies of people with similar hands, having similar characteristics. For instance: if a new born child has a short 'head line' or simian line, it is likely that,the child has "brain damage'.
I learnt this at medical school.

Comment: It's tempting to answer 'no' and leave it at that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In men the ratio between the length of the second and forth finger [are thought](http://web.psych.ualberta.ca/~phurd/papers/Bailey_andH05.pdf) to be an indication for the amount of prenatal testosterone. It allows for some inferences on personality traits that are associated with masculinity such as aggression.

There are a [few reports](http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,330667,00.html) of doctors identifying some specific brain tumors via handshakes.

White spots on fingernails can be a sign of a [possible Zinc Deficiency](http://jama.ama-assn.org/content/228/2/157.1.short).

Hand grip strength [seems](http://harvardpartnersinternational.staywellsolutionsonline.com/HealthNewsLetters/69,W1210c) to be a predictor for lifespan.

Most of what's commonly done under the label of palmistry however doesn't seem to be backed by research.

Comment: Could you extract relevant passage from those links. It would make browsing your answer a more enjoyable experience.

Comment: Further links (whose veracity I cannot vouch for): [SAT scores](http://www.livescience.com/7290-finger-length-predicts-sat-performance.html), [aggression](http://www.livescience.com/193-finger-length-predicts-aggression-men.html), [penis size](http://preventdisease.com/news/articles/index_finger_length_predicts_penis_size.shtml), [Boys with Longer Ring Fingers are Better at Math](http://science.slashdot.org/story/07/06/02/1339206/Boys-with-Longer-Ring-Fingers-are-Better-at-Math).

Comment: Why only in men? Women have testosterone as well

Answer (score 9):

[There is no relation between palmistry and reality](http://students.brown.edu/College_Hill_Independent/?p=2487).  Palmistry is generally a form of [cold reading](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/000081.html).  Much like phrenology, palmistry is a discredited practice.